# read MIDI messages from a Piano in Android

Tags: android, usb, midi

I would like to read and store midi messages sent from a piano. I do have a midi to Usb cable and I can connect it to my android phone, but I haven't found an answer on how to read what is sent. All questions are either speaking about midi files or not giving much answers.
My Galaxy S2 does work as midi host, so I was wondering if I there is a way were I just read raw info and then decipher it (using MIDI specs) or is there already something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[USB MIDI Logger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.kshoji.driver.midi.sample) shows the raw MIDI messages with USB devices.

And, the source code is also available on github.
https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver

Comment: ..and I suppose it's your library :-) I will have a look, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think Android by default has no idea about MIDI protocol.

So, you task breaks down to two things

- Read/write data to/from USB

For this read [Android USB Host API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html).

- Implement MIDI protocol

You can take a look at it [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~craig/articles/linuxmidi/misc/essenmidi.html). However, I believe you will need to do more research on this one.

Comment: I can't help with the first part, but there's already a Java implementation of MIDI available: http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

Comment: 2LeffelMania: I touched MIDI last time a decade ago. I believe MIDI protocol and MIDI file format are related but different things. So, mentioned library may or may not help.

Comment: I suppose I will have a look at kshoji's library.